# Как узнать, есть ли в моем компьютере evercookies?

Tags: cookie

Как узнать, есть ли в моем компьютере evercookies? Они же вроде скачиваются при посещении сайта на котором evercookies установлены и удалить их нереально?

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то попалась [такая статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/104725/), где подробно разъяснялось, что такое evercookie и как они работают.

Поскольку ссылки-ответы у нас не приветствуются – ниже краткая выжимка из статьи.

Ключевая особенность вечных cookie – то, что они хранятся не в одном каком-то хранилище, а сразу во многих и умеют при очистке одного (двух, трёх) хранилищ восстанавливаться, лишь бы осталась хотя бы одна копия в каком-то из них.

Посмотрите, сколько разных мест возможно для сохранения информации:

- HTTP Cookies;
- Local Shared Objects (Flash);
- Сохранение куки в значениях RGB автосгенерированных и форсированно кэшированных PNG с использованием HTML5 canvas;
- Сохранение куки в Web History;
- HTML5 Session Storage;
- HTML5 Local Storage;
- HTML5 Global Storage;
- HTML5 Database Storage через SQLite.

В принципе, это только то, что было известно на момент написания статьи, никто не мешает по мере развития технологий добавлять новые и новые хранилища.

Поэтому либо вы можете рискнуть и для своего браузера (вы не указали в вопросе, какой у вас) очищать все места, либо воспользоваться более сильнодействующими средствами.

Поставьте себе виртуальную машину и создайте снэпшот системы. Вернуться к нему можно нажав буквально пару кнопок – и этот способ гарантированно сотрёт информацию из всех хранилищ.

> Т.е. удалив все, я даже не узнаю, были ли у меня именно evercookie?

Для того конкретного скрипта пятилетней давности есть специальная страница, где можно определить, всё ли вычищено: жмите на click to rediscover.

Но это один конкретный скрипт одного конкретного человека, я не думаю, что разработчики коммерческих приложений захотят вам такие же скрипты проверки предоставить.

Comment: @A K Тем не менее, как я понимаю, данное действие сотрет вообще все с историей, обычными куки и кешем. Но как понять, что из этого именно evercookie. Вопрос принципиальный, как их отличить, чем они отличаются от обычных куки? Т.е. удалив все, я даже не узнаю, были ли у меня именно evercookie?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев Evercookie - это всего лишь термин для обозначения технологии, когда идентификатор клиента прячут по разным местам. Реализаций может быть много разных (и не о всех вам публично расскажут, разве что годы спустя приоткроют занавес) и каждый реализатор может понимать разный набор данных. Раньше флеш куки считалися "неубиваемыми" и что? С тех пор как про них прознали все привыкли и их чистить. А потом и флеш как технология умер. А сказать, что сейчас применяют - и это на очедном витке развития технологий уйдёт в массы. Это постоянная война щита и меча.

Comment: Вам видимо нужно самостоятельно проделать огромную исследовательскую работу: заходить на какой-то сайт в предположении, что он использует такую технологию, изучать, что он пишет куда (обвешавшись инструментами типа RegMon и контролируя, что в какие файлы пишется), потом второй, третий... И с удивлением узнать, что разные сайты используют достаточно разные наборы данных и единого понимания термина evercookie нет?

Answer (score 0):

chrome://settings/content/cookies

[image: скриншот]

Comment: А все остальные браузеры? :) Я вот к примеру пользуюсь Firefox'om.

Comment: @Yami, под остальные можешь запостить свой ответ ;)

Comment: И как с помощью этой картинки проверить, есть ли у меня именно evercookie?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, с помощью этой можно запретить для всех сайтов, вроде. А понять для конкретного можно нажав в адресной строке слева.

Comment: @Qwerty Я не собираюсь запрещать все куки для всех сайтов. Вопрос был касательно именно evercookie, в данном контексте это будет звучать как запретить именно evercookie и как мне узнать, что они у меня вообще есть (именно everccokie, а не обычные) ?

Comment: Если загуглить evercookies, то по первому же результату видим, что они иногда способны работать [«даже если пользователь сменит браузер»](https://habrahabr.ru/post/104725/). Вообще, evercookies совсем не обязательно имеют отношение к обычным cookies. Так что → не является ответом на вопрос

Comment: Т.е. тут никто не знает как их отличить от обычных куки, т.е. как их вообще определить, как запретить и как они вообще работают?

Answer (score -3):

Ты можешь посмотреть куда они записываются, и просто проверить эти хранилища в devtools.

https://samy.pl/evercookie/

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72580/discussion-on-answer-by-profesor08--------evercoo).

Comment: Зашел ради интереса посомтрел, что еще за devtools. Я вообще-то мозиллой пользуюсь. Можно было просто написать/ что посмотреть в инструментах разработчика. Тем не менее это не ответ на вопрос. И что зашел в инструменты разработчика, как человек поймет, что из всей этой кучи с куками и прочим является evercookie?

Comment: И каким это чудесным образом я должен был знать что ты пользуешься лисой? Тем не менее, это  webkit и тот-же devtools названный по другому. Все что есть на вкладке Application.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Интернет для всех и не делится на рунет/не рунет. Многие вещи требуют минимальный порог вхождения, если минимальные знания отсутствуют, то бесполезно что либо объяснять. Я бы мог скопипастить кусок текста из статьи, но вдруг в статье что-то изменится, ответ станет не верным.