# Идентификация анонимного пользователя ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Доброго времени суток!

В приложении возникла необходимость создать интерактивный сервис для пользователей (например голосование), но суть в том, что авторизация пользователей не планируется (из-за ненадобности).
Соответственно возникает вопрос релевантности такого голосования, если любой пользователь может голосовать неограниченное кол-во раз.

Как вариант рассматривал возможность идентификации с помощью [anonymousIdentification](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/91ka2e6a(v=vs.100)) .

В `Web.config` добавил

```
<anonymousIdentification
        enabled="true"
        cookieless="UseCookies"
        cookieName=".ASPXANONYMOUS"
        cookieTimeout="30"
        cookiePath="/"
        cookieRequireSSL="false"
        cookieSlidingExpiration = "true"
        cookieProtection="Validation"
      />
```

Далее в контроллере я могу получить значение куки:

```
var с = Request.Cookies[".ASPXANONYMOUS"].Value;
```

Дальше это значение я могу записать в БД и сверять наличие его в БД, что якобы даст возможность избежать повторного голосования, но при истечении действия куки или зачистке его пользователем, будет присвоено новое значение и пользователь может голосовать повторно.

Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли более универсальный способ идентифицировать пользователей и/или хранить информацию о них на длительный период? Или возможно для такой цели более целесообразно идентифицировать пользователей по ip?
Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей, буду признателен за любой совет или помощь. Спасибо!

Comment: Вам в сторону [evercookie](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/778442/213987) и понимать, что раз нет привязки - то это крайне просто будет обеспечить релевантное голосование. [Вот ещё](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/739736/213987) ссылки в ответе, посмотрите.

Comment: @A K, спасибо за совет, похоже на то, что может подойти. А средствами .Net подобной аналогии добиться нельзя получается?